# react call a bound method in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call my method `onModelSelect` in render()

If I call it `this.onModelSelect(model.id))` I then get the error `Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.` However it does output to `console.log`

So I am trying to call it like I would with an event handler `()=>this.onModelSelect(model.id))` but this doesn't output anything to `console.log`

what is the correct syntax to use to call my method??

```
export default class App extends Component {
          render() {
            onModelSelect = (modelId) => {
              this.props.selectModel(modelId);
              this.props.setModelSelected(true);
              console.log('test')
              console.log('modelId',modelId)
            }
              return(
                <div>
                  {this.props.models.length === 1 && this.props.models.map(model => ()=>this.onModelSelect(model.id))}
                </div>
              )
          }
      }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `render()` should return something to render, but you only return an empty `div` and try to call some methods? And it's a warning that suggests you not to do that, but not an error to prevent you from doing that.

Comment: That warning generates because `this.props.selectModel` and `this.props.setModelSelected` are causing side effects that should normally not happen inside `render`, so your intension might needs some fix.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call anything containing `this.setState` from your render method.

Actually, your `this.onModelSelect(model.id)` would return `Undefined function error` because you have to define `onModalSelect` function in your component not in your `render()` function

```
export default class App extends Component {
        onModelSelect = (modelId) => {
          this.props.selectModel(modelId);
          this.props.setModelSelected(true);
          console.log('test')
          console.log('modelId',modelId)
        }

      render() {
          return(
            <div>
              {this.props.models.length === 1 && this.props.models.map(model => ()=>this.onModelSelect(model.id))}
            </div>
          )
      }
  }
```

Comment: ah ok so I have moved this to the component as suggested but I still get this error

Comment: You could see if my comments below your question help.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `onModelSelect` method outside the render method

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue when you write like this:

```
.map(model => ()=>this.onModelSelect(model.id))
```

This says that `.map` callback returns function which in turn needs to be called to execute your function. Instead it should be:

```
.map(model => this.onModelSelect(model.id))
```

Also `.map` callback should return some value which in turn will be appended to array and will be rendered inside  element.

You should create `onModelSelect` method outside render function:

```
export default class App extends Component {
          onModelSelect = (modelId) => {
              this.props.selectModel(modelId);
              this.props.setModelSelected(true);
              console.log('test')
              console.log('modelId',modelId)
            }

          render() {
              return(
                <div>
                  {this.props.models.length === 1 && this.props.models.map(model => this.onModelSelect(model.id))}
                </div>
              )
          }
      }
```

Or if there is a legit use case and you want to put it in render function call it directly and not with this. Consider below code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
        let onModelSelect = (modelId) => {
          this.props.selectModel(modelId);
          this.props.setModelSelected(true);
          console.log('test')
          console.log('modelId',modelId)
        };
          return(
            <div>
              {this.props.models.length === 1 && this.props.models.map(model => onModelSelect(model.id))}
            </div>
          )
      }
  }
```